# How can I remove whitespace from a pathname in react

Tags: reactjs

The menu items in my dropdown are stored in an array called "lis". When the dropdown is open, the lis are mapped into it. Now I want to take the names not only as content, but also as a path to open the pages. And it works. My only problem is that some of the lis consist of two words. And I can't have a pathname with spaces. How can I remove this whitespace?
I tried to predefine it with lis.join(""), but the console tells me, undefined, so I obviously must find a way to do that in the map function.

code:

```
{
 item.lis.map((li, index)=>(
    <ul key={index}>
     <DropDownLi><Link to={{pathname:`/${li}`}} className="link" style={{color:"black"}}>{li}</Link></DropDownLi>
    </ul>
     ))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove spaces, as `str.replace(/\s+/g, '')` which replaces spaces,

```
{
 item.lis.map((li, index)=>(
    <ul key={index}>
     <DropDownLi><Link to={{pathname:`/${li.replace(/\s+/g, '')}`}} className="link" style={{color:"black"}}>{li}</Link></DropDownLi>
    </ul>
 ))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to create an array of objects where you would specify both the pathname and the actual list item.

```
item = [{item: "About Us", route: "/aboutus"}]

{
 item.map((li, index)=>(
    <ul key={index}>
     <DropDownLi><Link to={{pathname: li.route}} className="link" style={{color:"black"}}>{li.item}</Link></DropDownLi>
    </ul>
     ))
}
```

Other solution is replace `/${li}` with `/${li.replace(/\s+/g, '')}`, this will remove all the spaces from the `li` value.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the whitespace, you could encode it in the link with `encodeURIComponent`:

```
item.lis.map((li, index) => (
  <ul key={index}>
    <DropDownLi>
      <Link to={{ pathname: `/${encodeURIComponent(li)}` }} className="link" style={{ color: "black" }}>
        {li}
      </Link>
    </DropDownLi>
  </ul>
))
```